# How to snap and align 2 objects

Tags: snapping

[image]

Hi!
I'm a beginner learner and I'd like to know how to snap these three objects. I'd like to snap the two cylinders with the different faces of the cube. The short one on the left and the highest cylinder on the top of the cube. I'd like to have the center of the cylinder aligned with the center of the cube (the base of the cylinder inscribed into the face of the cube) 
I'm sorry for bad explanation
I hope someone can help me 
Thanks!

I add a screenshoot in which you can see what I have to do

Thanks again if someone can help me with this!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there's a faster way:

- Put the origin of the object you want to snap on its bottom face (first in *Edit* mode select the face, put the 3D cursor on the face with a <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then in *Object* mode set the origin to the 3D cursor (header menu bar > *Object* > *Set Origin*).

[image]

- Enable the *Snap* with these options: *Face* mode / *Align Rotation to Target* / *Project Individual Elements*.

[image]

- Snap the cylinder to the face you want.

[image]

- To align the cylinder with the cube, select the cylinder, then the cube. The cube being the last selected, it is said "active", it has a yellow line all around.

[image]

- Go in the header menu bar > *Object* > *Transform* > *Align Objects*.

[image]

- In the Operator box (bottom left) choose *Relative To* > *Active* and the axis you want your want your object to be aligned with (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select 2 objects.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A route to snapping aligned face-center to face-center for arbitrarily skewed objects via an intermediate parent...

Set Transform Orientation to 'Cursor'

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> go into the 'Cursor' tool. In its <kbd>N</kbd> > Tool tab settings, check 'Surface Project', and Orientation: 'Geometry'
- Drag the cursor over the source face until the orientation catches.
- In Edit Mode, select the source face, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to Selected'
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> create an Empty, with its creation orientation set to 'Cursor'
- The Empty is the wrong way round, so <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>180</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>parent the source object to the Empty.

[image]

- In the same way as you aligned the cursor to the source face, align it to the destination face.

[image]

- Empty selected, (Header) > Object menu > Transform > 'Align to Transform Orientation'

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Selected to Cursor'
- Source object selected, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Clear Parent and Keep Transform.

[image]

This would be a whole lot easier if <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to Selected' automatically aligned the cursor to the selected geometry, when the cursor tool was set that way. We should appeal to the devs. for that.