# How to align and snap objects?

Tags: snapping

[image]

Hi everyone!
I have to create this temple on Blender and I have no idea how to snap objects in this precise way. The biggest problem is how to snap the cubes with the green cylinders and cubes with blue ones in the sides of this temple. It seems they are aligned in the center but I'm not sure.
I hope someone can help me understand how to create this since I'm a very beginner with the software

Thanks!

Comment: Michelle, don't ask twice the same question, plus you already have 2 answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156443/how-to-snap-begginer-level/156450#156450

Answer (score 1):

The two answers you already got for this on your previous question are really the most accurate ways I know to do this. but if you're looking for something simpler then here are a couple more options for you.

1. You can snap everything to Blenders grid by either turning on the snap function here[image]

or by holding Ctrl as you move your objects.

2. Move objects along axis by entering a value, eg. if you have a cube that's 2 units long along the X-axis and its origin is in the middle[image] and you want to add another flush along side on the X axis, Duplicate the cube and press G, X, 2 to move it along the X [image]