# Exactly positioning and aligning objects

Tags: units

I'm trying to get productive with blender. Now I have this challenge I can't solve.
I imported parts of a cnc chair I'm designing. Precisely positioning the parts is my goal. How can I do this ?

So I want to go from here:
[image]

To here:

[image]

In the last screenshot the part look aligned but not exactly :(
I tried to figure out snapping but I get the impression that's not gonna cut it, I'd love something like sketchup style moving/rotating/positioning.

I've been also looking into the NP-station add on, I can't get that to work though.

Edit:

Thanks for the answers and replies. It looks like I want/need something like np-station or mesh align plus. Tiny-CAD only seems to work in edit mode (?) while I need to align and position objects. Getting into origin and the 3D cursor was useful too.

But I placing my bets on getting mesh align plus to work for now.

Comment: You will want the [TinyCAD](https://www.blender3darchitect.com/modeling-for-architecture/blender-2-8-cad-like-features-tinycad/) addon. It good face and vertex snapping tools.

Comment: Assuming no convenient alignment of object axes to faces, and arbitrarily skewed parts, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156469/35559) is one of a number of ways to align face-center to face-center... check out @moonboots' answer, too..

Answer (score 2):

Here are some useful tips for precise modeling in Blender:

01) Set your units to milimeters
*Properties Panel->Scene->Units->Length*

[image]

02) Set snapping to *Increments*
and enable *Absolute snapping*.

[image]

03) Use orthographic view and side views
This allows you to use grid better, and align precisely
Orthographic view shortcut: <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>
Viewpoint shortcut: <kbd>~</kbd> or use Numpad numbers.

*Switch to orthographic view and out*
[image]

*Use <kbd>~</kbd> to switch views*
[image]

04) Make use of Quad View
[image]

05) Learn to use *3D cursor* and work with *Object origin*.
These are very powerful together for precise object alignment.
[image]

06) Adjust your grid scale.
The default setting is good for most situations, but sometimes you may need to adjust it.

[image]

07) Blender is no CAD, but it will get you there :).
And as @Leander said - tinyCAD addon.
Enable it in *Preferences->Addons*  (and Save preferences)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my advice would be that if you want that to perfectly match you should model it first as a whole piece and then separate the object. in Edit mode you can also go to Viewport Overlays and Enable some Measurements.

Edit: You can also change the pivot to active element and use the scale option to 0 align some edges, vertices or faces, locking the axis you don't want to be deformed.

[image]

Comment: Uhm yeah, but my modelling skills at this moment are rhino, sketchup solidworks and a bit 3ds max. This model came from rhino. These are my first steps in blender and I would like to test/make shure that exact positioning and aligning can be done in a efficient way