# How to rotate or snap object parallel to specific face of another object?

Tags: snapping

I imported object from another file (bended detail), it appeared slightly rotated. So now i need to rotate it thus faces indicated with red arrows would be paralleled (and to the flat).

*attached file* https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KadW0M4l

[image]

I've found many tutorials about snapping. The most important information from them is that face snapping works with normals. And this info didn't helped me anyway =) None of them provide necessary result.

It's either snap the detail to flat by pivot point as it is expected without rotation enabled:

[image]

or rotate it in a ridiculous way:

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Robin Betts' answer could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156469/

Comment: @JachymMichal will try and reply

Comment: +1 for the question (I did not find any method to snap rotate as you are requesting). with the measure tool, I can only see that the rotation of the object is 20°. So if you select your object, R (to rotate), Z (to rotate only on Z axis), 20 (to rotate of 20°), you can get what you need.

https://i.imgur.com/8uKlXzD.png

Comment: @sanbaldo this is the good hand-made solving) I forgot about angle measurement. But I'm sure there must be another way to do it. Objects can be more complex and with more hard composition.

Comment: @JachymMichal and i did it! https://prnt.sc/rwuz9j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sanbaldo mentioned in comment section, we can use Measurement tool to determine angle between faces and rotate source detail.

In more complex situation this answer is available to solve this task:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156469/87633

Thanks to @JachymMichal

[image]

Comment: All credits to @RobinBetts :).

Comment: And congrats to you, I still can't fully understand Blender snapping :).

Answer (score 0):

Good example, made me break my head.
The main problem here is that transformations were applied to the curved model.
In fact, we need to reproduce them, and then rotate the object.
You can bind the created plane to the desired point using Face snapping and Align Rotation to Target. Then in the transformations of the plane, you need to selectively reset the one or two axis of rotation to 0 so that it aligns normally with the face of the curved figure.
After that, select the figure first, then the plane and apply Join. Now the local rotation of the figure has become the same as that of the plane.
We reproduced the rotation of the shape before applying the transformations. Now in Edit Mode select the plane and delete it.
After that, we reset all object rotation transformations to 0.
It will be aligned to one of the world axes. And then it is not difficult to align it as needed.